# Transform an existing type into a new type with one property change

Tags: typescript

How to transform an existing type into a new type with one property change?

[Typesctipt sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgYUWANhAHgFXNAXigGdgAnASwDsBzKAenqgCsBXUqAMzjKmwEMEGCACgRjKAGN%20VKnGBQARtEkALGTQgATEaEhQA8mGAU4VYgB4cAPihEA3iKjOocYwEYAXErhxMMqAAfKFYqLQhOam0AbicXN2AAJm8qVgRlMliXV2MAZgB%20b3gkVCFMXHws%20OMAFm8cEQBfMQlkAOUpdVptFqYACTgAdyhgOE6NaAT3EbH%20SUkIY1cqdBARslZoGS0oak4IXnlVA5yTMxH8YnzdfCgAaQgQYjsoAGtHuE5DY1NzCxkQNYxJgFGRvPYoABtO67Kj3R7EAC63hh2GAEDCzwA5FMsVB8utNlBvACoM1xEwAOK%20HYACmIqjgrHQO0GPFeAEoRLwHKcvISIAAaU7JKCJYUJXLeLHuLES2reabNHlQCFTbzkTbypLecWnKVQGVy051Q2kMh48kSABC-DpDKZLKU0AOZB4XJVao83k4-HQxCFIsV2oNWPNxoSpqVDCYUxIjOZOw6mtEnr5Go2gYSorD5AjeWl4e1UbJMZF8cdSegqXSB25Ly9wH5Ke1OaL%20uDJsVpYkkoriedsEQKDQ5TwkCAA)

Example:

```
type SomeComplexType = string // just for example

// cannot be changed
type Options<T> = {
    opt1: boolean | undefined;
    opt2: number;
    opt3?: SomeComplexType;
    opt4: T
}

// Can be changed

// How to change opt1 to accept only true and infer other option types?
type Keys = keyof Options<any>

let r: { [K in Keys]: K extends 'opt1' ? true : any }

// Good (should work)
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 2, opt3: '1', opt4: 1 }
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 2, opt3: '1', opt4: 'str' }

// Bad (should be error)
r = { opt1: false, opt2: 1, opt3: 'str', opt4: 1 } // opt1 should be true
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 'str', opt3: 'str', opt4: 1 } // opt2 should be number
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 'str', opt3: 1, opt4: 1 } // opt3 should be
```

Comment: You might be looking for `Options<any>[K]` as in [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3QQw) but your examples seem to be largely in error so I'm not sure.  Also, what are you trying to convey by having `Options` be generic?  If the question isn't about generics, then maybe the example code should remove its dependency on them?  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7blRw).

Comment: @jcalz sorry, my bad about wrong examples, changed examples. Your answer is correct, please post it so i could accept (first link).

Comment: I'm still suggesting that we edit this question to remove any mention of generics or even `SomeComplexType` since, while it might matter to your use case, doesn't relate to the actual question, which is about how to transform an existing type into a new type where just one of the properties from the original type has been modified and the rest are left alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object type `O` and would like to make a new type where all the proptery keys and values are the same except that the property at key `opt1` should be `true`, you can write it like this:

```
{ [K in keyof O]: K extends 'opt1' ? true : O[K] }
```

The syntax `O[K]` is an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) meaning "the type of the property of `O` with a key of type `K`".

Then your examples should work as desired, (assuming `O` is `Options<any>`):

```
// Good 
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 2, opt3: '1', opt4: 1 } // okay
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 2, opt3: '1', opt4: 'str' } // okay

// Bad 
r = { opt1: false, opt2: 1, opt3: 'str', opt4: 1 } // error!
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 'str', opt3: 'str', opt4: 1 } // error!
r = { opt1: true, opt2: 'str', opt3: 1, opt4: 1 } // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgYUWANhAHgFXNAXigGdgAnASwDsBzKAenqgCsBXUqAMzjKmwEMEGCACgRjKAGN+VKnGBQARtEkALGTQgATEaEhQA8mGAU4VYgB4cAPihEA3iKjOocYwEYAXErhxMMqAAfKFYqLQhOam0AbicXN2AAJm8qVgRlMliXV2MAZgB+b3gkVCFMXHws+OMAFm8cEQBfMQlkAOUpdVptMT1oAztDY1NzCxkQa1iRTAUyb3soAG0AaShqKABrCBA4TkMAXW9V7GAIMOIoAHIE90uofKhyVmhvAxX9qGbxJgBxXy0oCJeA4csAvI8yM8ADSg5JQRIwhK5byXW6I2redyfBhMOAbfggIGDBY3bxPCDopLeBGg5FXNGgupXUhkO6NHGufGE75QABC-ABRJBpK4-HQxApsMxlLplxZl0pTKx7IkEDIZB4AEIhVASR4yZDJQk4XLyAraSj5YrMdjVeqtTq9WCDdCpcyzTLpYybSqmGqNWRNUA)